# Need to attach a dropdown to an icon with type "button"

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I have an icon on a twitter bootstrap container. I want to click on it and have a dropdown show up with different options that contain links to other sites. Right now, I can get the dropdown, but it shows up automatically on the page without the icon being clicked and it's each link on top of each other. 
Basically I want the functionality of any of "buttons" like "file, edit, source, navigate..." etc in eclipse, where you click on it and the dropdown appears. But I need this to be attached to an icon. Here is what I tried unsuccessfully:

```
  <a id="myIcon" href="#" class="btn-mini" type="button"><i class="icon-wrench"  title="Help" ></i></a>
    <div id="helpMenu" class="menu">
        <a class="menuItem" href="#">Help</a>
        <a class="menuItem" href="#">Ideas</a>
        <a class="menuItem" href="#">Issues</a>
    </div>
```

I feel like I'm overlooking a simple solution. Any advice?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to add the appropriate `data-` attributes to your markup and it's probably best to put the drop down in a list, e.g.

```
<div class="dropdown">
  <a role="button" data-toggle="dropdown" href="#"><i class="icon-wrench"  title="Help" ></i></a>
  <ul class="dropdown-menu" role="menu" aria-labelledby="dLabel">
    <li role="presentation"><a role="menuItem" href="#">Help</a></li>
    <li role="presentation"><a role="menuItem" href="#">Ideas</a></li>
    <li role="presentation"><a role="menuItem" href="#">Issues</a></li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: thank you! That did work, however, the dropdown doesn't pop up from the icon, but from the lefthand side of the container (the icon is on the far right of the container) any ideas why it came up in the wrong spot?

Comment: I'm completely new to js, jquery, html, css and the like, so I'm not sure how to display it right in jsfiddle, I tried. So basically, it all depends on my CSS?

Comment: got it. I had to adjust right, top, left, and padding. Thanks again!